# Are Japanese capacitors more reliable in general?

Tags: consumer-products, electronics

Motherboard and PSU manufacturer's marketing department typically like to highlight the fact that they use Japanese capacitors, and there are even [videos on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAiK6FF6vr0) and [some articles](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/How-to-Identify-Japanese-Electrolytic-Capacitors/595) about how to identify if a capacitor is Japanese.

Is there any conclusive evidence to suggest that Japanese capacitors are more reliable than, let's say, American capacitors?

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 7):

You picked the wrong country for comparison.
It is the [Chinese/Taiwanese Capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) that's relevant here:
[Epidemic of Faulty Capacitors from China](http://theeestory.com/topics/6139)
--- [“capacitor plague” – Dell laptops](http://www.dellsony.info/capacitor-plague-dell-laptops/).
Supposedly the manufacturers have cleaned up their act, but trust comes hard to engineers after events like this.

Comment: Thanks for the links, which actually answers most of my question. Even though the answer is on Wikipedia, it's hard to find the right article when you don't know where to begin searching.